# Cut word from column and paste to new column

Tags: python, pandas

On printing AllTogetherNoNan_df.head()

```
0    Null Null Null Misty Morn Null Horsefen Road Great Yarmouth NR29 5QJ Ludham Null      
1    Null Null 16 St Catherines Way Null Gorleston Norfolk NR31 7QB Great Yarmouth Null    
3    Null Null 21 Links Road Null Gorleston Norfolk NR31 6JP Great Yarmouth Null           
4    Null Null Null Ground Floor Null Back Flat Gorleston NR31 6AL 15 Upper Cliff Road Null
6    Null Null 3 The Boulters Null Gorleston Norfolk NR31 6TF Great Yarmouth Null
```

[Excel File](https://send.firefox.com/download/db7454a06723d8ce/#NGeq1X4SBIQKa8wYsjpcww)

I would like to cut county Norfolk and paste it to new column 'County'

Comment: Wait so you want to remove string `Norfolk` from that specific column to a new column `County`. The confusing part is, do just want to remove the row which has the string `Norfolk` in that column specific column (In you case, 8th) ?

Comment: This is one big column (row 0 , 1, 3, 4 6, as example). The goal is to separate everything like street number, street name, city, county, postcode. If I know how to do it with one word I will apply logic to the rest.

Comment: Can you change the question to show the actual csv or file. The `Head()` output is just hard to say which columns have 'Norfolk'

Comment: Excel file included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in two steps

1. Copy Over 'Norfolk', if column string has 'Norfolk' substring
2. Strip original column.

   ```
   def copy(row):
       if 'Norfolk' in row[col_index_in_question]:
           return 'Norfolk'

   def strip(row):
       return row[col_index_in_question].replace('Norfolk', '')


   df['County'] = df.apply(copy, axis=1)
   df[col_index_in_question] = df.apply(strip, axis=1)
   ```

Replace `col_index_in_question` with you column index

But more importantly if it's a specific formatted address that you want to parse, you can use this [Python Parser Lib](https://parserator.datamade.us/usaddress)

Comment: For some reason print df['Country'] gives me None everywhere. No results on second part at all. Only KeyErrors. I feel like I'm missing something simple here, lack of python knowledge probably.

Comment: Changed the answer a bit. But it's `None` because we are not returning anything if the column does not contain the substring 'Norfolk'.

Comment: Hmm, but when you check my example above you can see Norfolk in line 1,3,6 etc. I have many  many more. btw. I won't be able to use PythonParser Lib as I deal with UK addresses mostly.

Comment: The above code should work. I don't know why you are getting `None` try `df['County']` not `df['Country']`. Also the file attached is that the file you are reading because the `col_index_in_question ` has to be specifically which col you want to target

Comment: Thank you. I have created whole script again and is working.